# What does the Google Chrome exactly do when a new tab is opened?

Tags: google-chrome, process, operating-system, browser, fork

Today, i observed an interesting behavior. I am using windows XP-sp3 OS.
When i open a new tab in Google Chrome & view the task manager, a new process is created.
But, after some time, this process is terminated.

Why it is showing such kind of behavior? Is it due to system call `vfork()`? Does the child process immediately call `exec()`?

Does it happen only with Google Chrome or all other browsers behave in a similar fashion?

Comment: Chromium, the open-source components behind Google Chrome, [is an open-source project](http://www.chromium.org/Home), meaning you can download and browse their source to determine their implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK Chrome maintains one process for each tab, also one process for some plugins too. They preferred multi-process architecture over multi-threaded one because when you are making network application which communicate with network all the time, you can expect to receive packets which can garble the memory. So having multi-process will prevent all but one process, as opposed to multi-threaded will kill the the tabs.

You can enlighten your self on following blog:

http://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html